# How to save/open files on server with GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, birt

I have a BIRT report that I've created in GWT and I'd like to save it to the server and then open it back up. I feel like hardcoding the url is the wrong route to go (ie C:/files/foo/foo.html) but I'm not having much luck figuring out another way of doing it. I tried using GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles() but if i use that I get an unsatisfied link error in BIRT. What can I use to save/open a file, what is considered the best practice? Thanks.

edit: bad wording, the BIRT report is generated server-side. I'd like to be able to save it server side and then open it up in a new browser window (using window.open I'd imagine?). Nothing is uploaded from the client side.

Comment: Hi, if your file is on the client, and you want to save it to the server, you must send it to the server with some upload mechanism. I recommend [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html). I'm not familiar with BIRT, but `UnsatisfiedLinkError` happens when you try to use a server side method/class from the client side. The `GWT` class is only for use with the client side.

Comment: let me rephrase it a little. The report is generated server side, I want to save it server side and then open it back up. Nothing needs to be uploaded because the client is not creating anything.

Comment: In this case, it is a matter of getting the URL correct. If you are sure that the URL is visible to the client (test it by visiting it on a browser), then you can use a combination of `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` and `GWT.getModuleName()` to help you parse the correct URL. You can then use `Window.open()` to open the URL for the client.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention one thing. Make sure your report saves somewhere in your `WAR` directory. That is the only way my earlier suggestion would work. A good path is `war/PROJECT_NAME/` I know you mentioned `C:/files/foo/foo.html` but that directory won't be the same when you deploy your application to a web server.

Comment: I tried testing it with 'GWT.GetModuleBaseURL()' and 'GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles()' and both give me a url that is not visible to the client (I get a 404 error). Actually its the same url in my testing.

Comment: Just saw your comment. I'm saving to /projectname/WAR/reports/

Comment: This should get your the correct URL: `GWT.getModuleBaseURL().replace(GWT.getModuleName()+"/", "") + "reports/" + <YOUR FILE NAME HERE>;` 
Then use it with Window.open()

Comment: tried your suggestion churro, I still get a unsatisfied link error in my console

Comment: Just to clarify one more time, are you trying to show your report to the user of your application on the client side? If you call my code from the server side, it will not work (you will get `UnsatisfiedLinkError`). Your client side code has to use my code. You have to send the file name of the report to your client side code somehow, maybe with an asynchronous call. The client side will then do `Window.open()` to show it. The only other way to get the report to the client is to stream the contents of the file as a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BIRT report is a static file (Not generated during the runtime of your application) You can create a simple Servlet that read the file and copy the data to the `OutputStream` of the response. If it's generated at the runtime, the client will request it to the server, the server will generate it and return the URL location of the report. The client can open the report with that URL.

### Example:

If your BIRT is located under foo/foo.bar you can map a servlet as /foo/*. After mapping it the user will request the url `www.yourselver.com/foo/foo.bar` The servlet at the `doGet` method can read the file and stream the content back to the client.

Comment: let me rephrase it a little. The report is generated server side, I want to save it server side and then open it back up. Nothing needs to be uploaded because the client is not creating anything.

Comment: Hey, I didn't had the time to create mocks of this. But this explains what I mean. Just replace the JSP code with GWT: http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

Comment: Hey Andre, can you give an example of the GWT code that would replace it? the doGet method has input parameters and the JSP code does not (I'm not familiar with JSP). is there a special way of implementing it?